# Trouble deploying Nodejs App + Python on Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, heroku, procfile, dyno

I know this question has been asked a million times but none of the solutions have worked so far for me.

I have a nodejs app; typical reactjs frontend and express backend. The backend calls a python script for JSON to excel export. This script uses only xlsxwriter as its dependency.

I deployed the entire app on Heroku with only nodejs buildpack and it works. Only the python script was failing, which I understand. So I added python buildpack too. Also according to the suggestions online, I added a Procfile too.

Procfile:

```
web: npm run-script build
web: npm run-script start
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

But I am getting this error:

> at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
> host=********.herokuapp.com
> request_id=44a72675-13a5-4738-bd2e-c2d592806dab fwd="103.76.211.162"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

So I understand my web dyno is not starting. Question is why? I can see this on my Heroku dashboard.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid actually. I hadn't turned on the dynos from my dashboard as visible in the picture. After that, it works perfectly.